# How can I extract the four first numbers from a variable? R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, numbers

Well, I got a variable that shows numbers like this one: 13015064000992062, and I need to extract the four first numbers and put it in another column. In this case, it will be 1301.

A friend told me that it was using stringr library, but he can't remember the code.

I am working with a data frame. So I need to get a new variable called "canton", that are the four first digits from 'Identificador'

So it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `substr`

```
 permMan19$newcol <- substr(permMan19$identificador, 1, 4)
```